# AUTH not available (Net::SMTPAuthenticationError) in Ruby 1.9.2

Tags: ruby, smtp

I am trying to send mail from MS exchange server but I am getting error as

**`check_auth_response': 503 #5.3.3 AUTH not available (Net::SMTPAuthenticationError)**

The code I used to send mail is

```
require 'net/smtp'
require 'mail'

smtp = Net::SMTP.new('mycompanydomain',25)
smtp.start('mycompanydomain', 'name@company.com', 'pwd',:plain) do |smtp|
  # code to send mail
end
```

Note: It works fine with Gmail account but fails for company account.
Any help would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that your server supports `AUTH`?  You can find out by:

If the connection is not encrypted:

```
telnet mycompanydomain 25
ehlo testing
```

It should respond with something that that says `AUTH PLAIN` in it.  If it doesn't, your server does not support plain auth, it may list other auth methods.  You may need to set it to one of them.

More information http://qmail.jms1.net/test-auth.shtml